# Mount with VirtualBox erased home directory?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, home-directory, data-recovery

I have a new(ish) installation of Ubuntu in a VirtualBox, with OSX as a host machine. I was attempting to mount a shared folder into Ubuntu, so typed in the terminal:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf VBShare ~/
```

...or similar, expecting to mount the folder in my home. However, what appears to have happened is that the folder has *replaced* my home folder, which now just contains the files from the shared folder.

(There is a chance I also tried something like:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf VBShare /home/michael/
```

)

What has happened? Is recovery a possibility? What should I have done instead? I haven't tried a restart yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run

`sudo umount ~`

to unmount the drive. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29656/does-a-mountpoint-have-to-be-an-empty-directory) about `mount` overwriting directories.

In the future, you should make a new directory and then mount to there. For example

`sudo mkdir /media/Share`

`sudo mount -t vboxsf VBShare /media/Share`.

Comment: Great, thanks. When I try to umount, though, I get the error: `umount: /home/michael/: device is busy.` There seem to be three processes using it, one of which is gnome-terminal. How can I stop these safely?

Comment: What directory are you calling the command from? If your shell is currently at `~` then it won't work because you're using that directory. Just `cd ..` and run it again.

Comment: Excellent, I did that and also learned about the `-l` (lazy unmount) switch, which has worked a trick. Thanks a bunch.