# Why do "df" and "du" commands show different disk usage?

Tags: disk-usage

I cannot access ubuntu system on my pc, the error message: "*the system is running in low graphics mode*" and I tried some commands I searched from internet.

I found out a problems seems there is no available disk space. I used "**df**" and "**du**" commands to check, the results are as follow:

```
du -j --max-depth=1
23G  ./home
3.3G ./usr 
...... 
28G
```

and

```
df -Th 
filesystem   Type   size    used   available   use%    mounted on 
/dev/sda5    ext4   68G     68G    0           100%    /
```

how would I clean up the system for more disk space?

Comment: The question in the title and at the end of the question body is pretty different. Some answers are related to one question, some to the other. You should clarify your actual needs and possibly [accept](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer, too.

Answer (score 67):

You most probably know that you can remove a file that still in use by some application and for this application it remains available. It because file descriptor in /proc/ filesystem is held open.

So if there are such open descriptors to files already removed, space occupied by them considered as used by `df` (and `df` is right), but they can not be taken into account by `du` due to there are no longer filenames associated with them.

You can find all unlinked but held open files with:

```
# lsof | grep '(deleted)'
```

Comment: This just saved me. Had no idea why my disk was full, but du said it was empty. An open file handle for a 8GB file

Comment: How can i delete the links?

Comment: Sometimes you need to execute this as root to see deleted files held open by processes of other users.

Comment: The root cause of this for me ended up being an incorrect log file spec in one of my `/etc/logrotate.d` files. The bad entry was missing a postrotate routine, which caused my daemon process to not let go of its rotated / deleted files.

Comment: how could I remove those unlinked but open files?

Answer (score 22):

> How can i delete the links? –  Vikas Hardia Aug 22 '14 at 5:46

You must find the the process which holds the file handle. Use the command of Dmitry Alexandrov, there you see the process and pid. In our case and "old" varnish log file was the space killer.

```
# lsof | grep '(deleted)'
[...]
varnishlo 13978       varnishlog    3w      REG              252,1 318448027646    5926973 /var/log/varnish/varnish.log.1 (deleted)
apache2   16801         www-data    2w      REG              252,1        64550   13110120 /var/log/apache2/error.log.1 (deleted)
[...]
# service varnishlog stop
[or if there is no service script]
# kill -11 13978 (the second number of the lsof command is the pid)
[or may be] 
# kill -9 13978
```

Don't forget to start the service or process again if it is a demon or some other service on your computer.
If you can, just reboot the computer ;)

Answer (score 14):

Ok, lets check the man pages:

> df - report file system disk space usage

and

> du - **estimate** file space usage

Those two tools were meant for different propose. While `df` is to show the file system usage, `du` is to report the file space usage. `du` works from files while `df` works at filesystem level, reporting what the kernel says it has available. Continue reading the `du` manpage support this:

> Summarize disk usage of each **FILE**, recursively for directories.

it says `du` works with files.

> `df` displays the
>          amount of disk space available on the **file system** containing each  file
>          name  argument.   If  no file name is given, the space available on all
>          currently mounted file systems is shown.

here says that `df` do not care about the files but the filesystem itself.

Comment: du usage can be modified with the -x character, to tell it to only count files on the given file system.

Answer (score 1):

```
df
```

Summarize free disk space

It displays the amount of disk space available .

```
du
```

Summarize disk usage.

It displays the amount of disk space used.

Comment: yes, but in the result of "df -Th", it showed 68G used. today morning when i try to access ubuntu system, it still gives "the system is running in low-graphics mode" message, but when i check the memory usage, the "df" and "du" commands shows a reasonable result. But what;s the problem with the "low-graphics mode"?

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error).

Answer (score 1):

Simply said:

You ran `du` without root permissions. So it is not able to check the available space in `/proc`, `/mnt`, etc, folders.

`df` showed the total used & free space respectively.

So when you check the Linux root file system, take the `du` report as final.

Answer (score 0):

nothing that much confusing : Here is look :=

1) du == Disk Usage
  How much disk space is being used by these files?

2) df == Disk Free
   How much free disk space do we have?

Also for the system is running in low graphics mode '[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)'

Answer (score 0):

I did 
`sudo du -hxa  / | egrep '^[[:digit:]]{1,1}G[[:space:]]*'`

It exactly accounted for the big discrepancy of 21GB that I was seeing!
The file in question was /swap file if 21GB!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case lsof did not help. I was able to track this down because I had mounted disk images using losetup as loop devices. Even after unmounting these devices and deleting the corresponding images there were processes that maintained some sort of indirect reference to the disk images.

So in short, `sudo ps -ef|grep loop` then `sudo losetup -d /dev/loopX`. This is not a direct answer to why du and df disagree but it has come up often enough for me that I was able to finally figure out the reason why which was different from any answer I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my situation in case it helps someone. In my case, `du` reported 6G used and `df` reported 23G used -- a 17G difference!

But my problem was, I had a folder on the primary disk at `/mnt/data` with 17G of files in it, and then a SSD mounted at `/mnt/data` -- the result was the SSD mount essentially hid the data on the primary disk.

So check if it's possible you have other disks mounted on a non-empty directory on the disk in question. (ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/29657)