# Large discrepancy between df and du

Tags: filesystem, disk, disk-usage

My `/` partition which holds everything (including `/home`), was suddenly using 100% of disk space. I removed a few files and now `df` shows

```
$ df -h /dev/sda1 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       214G  149G   54G  74% /
```

However `du` shows:

```
$ sudo du -shxc /*
9.6M    /bin
66M /boot
4.0K    /cdrom
4.0K    /dev
16M /etc
26G /home
0   /initrd.img
0   /initrd.img.old
504M    /lib
3.5M    /lib32
4.0K    /lib64
0   /libnss3.so
16K /lost+found
92K /media
4.0K    /mnt
3.3G    /opt
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4708/task/4708/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4708/task/4708/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4708/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/4708/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
0   /proc
346M    /root
1.9M    /run
13M /sbin
136K    /srv
0   /sys
36K /tmp
6.3G    /usr
1.1G    /var
0   /vmlinuz
0   /vmlinuz.old
37G total
```

I used `sudo`, only `/proc` cannot be accessed and knowing what is done on the machine, `du` seems to be right. However allocating disk space for more than the 54G `df` says are left indeed fails:

```
$ fallocate -l 55G test.img
fallocate: test.img: fallocate failed: No space left on device
```

I know about [Difference between baobab and df/du](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395611/difference-between-baobab-and-df-du) and [df shows all space taken, but du doesn't add up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256619/df-shows-all-space-taken-but-du-doesnt-add-up) which seem to show the same problem, but there is no answer regarding how to solve it. I also know about [Why do df and du show different output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/209934/why-do-df-and-du-show-different-output), but the difference is very large here, I rebooted the machine, I checked `/dev/sda1` while booted from a DVD so it should really not be there anymore.

Does anyone knows what is happening. I would really like my disk space back! ;)

System information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux hjort 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-amd64:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-amd64:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem was identical to the on in this post https://serverfault.com/questions/57098/du-vs-df-difference

Sorry for the trouble. I had `rsnapshot` backups in `/mnt/backup` (by mistake) and then mounted the backup drive on top of them.