# Why do `ls` and `du` commands show a different size for the same file?

Tags: command-line, files, filesystem, ls, du

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04.

When I check a file's size using the `du` command, I get the following output:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-39:/myxfs$ du -h newquota
4.0K    newquota
```

With the `ls -la` command, I get the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-49-39:/myxfs$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu   22 Apr 18 19:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root   root   4096 Apr 17 12:05 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 1024 Apr 18 19:17 newquota
```

Why is there a difference in size for the same file? And what is the actual size of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do "df" and "du" commands show different disk usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280342/why-do-df-and-du-commands-show-different-disk-usage) Because a file can contain 10 bytes of data, but if the file system block size is 4096 bytes, the file will take up 4096 bytes of space.

Comment: these answers are not completely answering my question. Could someone please explain in detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of a file, `ls` shows the actual size of the file ... While `du` shows the space on the disk reserved/occupied by the file ... Filesystems differ in minimum size allocation to a certain file ... Most filesystems will reserve a minimum of a block size which in your filesystem's case appears to be `4.0K`.

Think of it as the standard size of a room in a hotel ... Hotels will accommodate a guest in the standard room size they have ... That same room  might accommodate two or three guests as well ... But in all cases each guest/group of guests(*whether one, two or three*) occupy the same minimum allocatable room space ... Hotel rooms are filesystem blocks and guests are files contents (metaphorically).

So either:

- an empty block(*also empty files as well are merely metadata"e.g. names and inodes ... etc" that count towards the size of their parent directory but no actual size reserved for them on disk yet*).
- or an occupied block(*i.e. a file with contents less or equal to the block size*)

Please see the demonstration below:

```bash
# Show block size
$ stat -fc %s .
4096 # 4.0K
$ touch file
$ head -c 1k /dev/urandom > file
$ du -h file 
4.0K    file
$ ls -la file 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1024 Apr 19 00:21 file
```