26GB disk missing
Ubuntu 20.04
disk 50GB
df -h == Used 43 GB as shown in the screenshot.
du -h --max-depth=1 / | sort -h == 17 GB as shown in the screenshot.
26GB disk missing (43GB - 17GB = 26GB)?
How to check disk missing?


Welcome to ASK. Take at look at the answers for this question to give a number of reasons for this apparent discrepancy: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/280342/why-do-df-and-du-commands-show-different-disk-usage

You are using LVM which is volumes inside one partition. Often used on servers or if you specify full drive encryption. Entire volume is not allocated so you can add volumes or expand your / if desired. https://askubuntu.com/questions/3596/what-is-lvm-and-what-is-it-used-for & https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm
